# TabBar / CollectionView crash

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a mainController which inherits from UITabBarController. Inside, I set up my view controllers like so:

```
func setupControllers() {
    let chatController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ChatController())

    let homeController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController())



    viewControllers = [chatController, homeController]
}
```

Inside the 'homeController' view controller, I have added a collectionView subview which is setup in the viewDidLoad function.

class HomeController: UIViewController {

```
let userCollectionView = UserCollectionView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupSubviews()
}

private func setupSubviews() {

    view.addSubview(userCollectionView)
    userCollectionView.protocolDelegate = self
    userCollectionView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .zero, size: .init(width: view.frame.width, height: 108))
}
}
```

And inside the UserCollectionView, inside viewDidLoad I'm have some firebase observers which query and pull data to store inside the collectionView via 'insertItems / reloadItems' methods.

When I load the app, it crashes. And I've pinned it down to that the userCollectionView saying 'invalid items in section' etc because I'm loading the collectionView cells one at a time, rather than a complete collectionView reload via self.reloadData().

When I change the loading order of my viewControllers to [homeController, chatController] it works fine, as that is the first viewController that is loaded. But when I switch it to [chatController, homeController] it crashes.

I have tried setupSubviews in viewWillAppear, however the app still crashes.

Even removing the setting up of the colletionView, and just having the instance:

```
let userCollectionView = UserCollectionView()
```

crashes.

Crash Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Which I know is related to the collectionView 'insertItems / reloadItems' functions inside, as if I remove them, no issue. I don't see why it would crash, as homeController is still being loaded with all the methods / firebase observers to popular the userCollectionView inside it.. it just isn' the initial viewController the app shows upon launch.

How would I fix this issue?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Had the add the observers function inside the viewDidAppear method.

That way, when the homeController tab is pressed, the observers are called and update the collectionView.

I'm curious as to why it would crash anyways, as there is data to insert into the collectionView. Does the viewController that is updating it's subviews have to be visible in order to be valid?